# High Order and Low-order byte

Tags: c, bit, console-output, console-input

> The prototypes for getchar() and putchar() are:

> int getchar(void);

> int putchar(int c);

> As ,its prototype shows, the getchar() function is
> declared as returning an integer.However, you can assign this value to
> a char variable, as is usually done, **because the character is
> contained in the low-order byte.(The high-order byte is normally
> zero.)**
>
> Similary in case of putchar(),even though it is declared as taking an
> integer parameter you will generally call it using a character
> argument.**Only the low order byte of its parameter is actually output
> to the screen.**

**What do you mean by high order and low order bytes?**

Comment: An int data type is either 16 or 32 bits - either 2 or 4 bytes.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: Burn the book...

Comment: Out of curiosity, what source is this from?

Comment: Please dont confuse C and C++. Is this one of the HS books, BTW?

Comment: You should *not* normally assign `getchar()` to a `char` variable, because `getchar()` will eventually return `EOF`, which has lots of high-order 1s. (Also because some input characters will be returned as positive integers outside of the range of a signed `char`, which is Undefined Behaviour.) My recommendation: find a better book.

Comment: I'll join the crowd here and suggest getting a better C++ book. There's a great list on the site here if you search for it.

Answer (score 16):

In C, the size of an `int` is implementation defined, but is usually 2, or 4 bytes in size. The high-order byte would be the byte that contains the largest portion of the value. The low-order byte would be the byte that contains the smallest portion of the value. For example, if you have a 16-bit `int`, and the value is 5,243, you'd write that in hex as 0x147B. The high order byte is the 0x14, and the low-order byte is the 0x7B. A `char` is only 1 byte, so it is always contained within the lowest order byte. When written in hex (in left-to-right fashion) the low-order byte will always be the right-most 2 digits, and the high-order byte will be the left-most 2 digits (assuming they write all the bytes out, including leading 0s).

Answer (score 4):

I think the best analogy for this would be to look at decimal numbers.

Although this isn't literally how things work, for the purposes of this analogy let's pretend that a `char` represents a single decimal digit and that an `int` represents four decimal digits. If you have a `char` with some numeric value, you could store that `char` inside of an `int` by writing it as the last digit of the integer, padding the front with three zeros. For example, the value `7` would be represented as `0007`. Numerically, the `char` value `7` and the `int` value `0007` are identical to one another, since we padded the `int` with zeros. The "low-order digit" of the `int` would be the one on the far right, which has value `7`, and the "high-order bytes" of the `int` would be the other three values, which are all zeros.

In actuality, on most systems a `char` represents a single byte (8 bits), and an `int` is represented by four bytes (32 bits). You can stuff the value of a `char` into an `int` by having the three higher-order bytes all hold the value 0 and the low-order byte hold the `char`'s value. The low-order byte of the `int` is kinda sorta like the one's place in our above analogy, and the higher-order bytes of the `int` are kinda sorta like the tens, hundreds, and thousands place in the above analogy.

Comment: @templatedef can i  infer that when integer or any other type(numeric type) gets typecasted to a char var then that char variable contains the low order byte of the numeric type?

Comment: @rimiro, no you can't. If you convert an integer to an `unsigned char`, you will get the low order bits (at least 8 of them). But converting a number outside of the range to a signed `char' is not defined by the standard, so you have to search the documentation for the compiler(s) you use (which you also need to do to see whether`char` is signed or unsigned).

Comment: Actually, the length of the data types is dependent on the used architecture and the compiler. While `char` is one byte long (8 bits) in most cases, `int` may be either 16 bits long (two bytes) on 8/16-bit systems, or 32 bits long (four bytes) on 16/32-bit systems. Make use of the `sizeof(int)` statement to make sure what length your `int` datatype occupies in memory.